# Pig - Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.ISOToUnix as multiple or none of them fit

Tags: datetime, hadoop, apache-pig, epoch

I'm simply trying to convert a date time format in pig into epoch time so I can do other calculations with the time. Here is my (partial) script below:

```
DEFINE ISOToUnix org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.ISOToUnix();
A = LOAD 's3://hearstlogfiles/google/NetworkBackfillImpressions_271283/2014/09/24/NetworkBackfillImpressions_271283_20140924_00.gz' USING PigStorage(',');
B = LIMIT A 10;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE
(chararray)(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING($0, 0,10),' '),SUBSTRING($0, 11,19) )) as   dt_string:chararray,
DATE_TIME(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING($0, 0,10),' '),SUBSTRING($0, 11,19) )) AS dt;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE 
dt_string, 
dt, 
ISOToUnix(dt)/1000 as epoch:long;
DUMP D;
```

When pig tries to execute the line below, I get the error right below it. I know I cast dt as the right format.

```
ISOToUnix(dt)/1000 as epoch:long  
Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.ISOToUnix as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
```

When I DUMP C, I get the following. So I know C dt is in the right format.

```
(2014-09-24 02:53:54,2014-09-24T02:53:54.000Z)  
(2014-09-24 02:57:54,2014-09-24T02:57:54.000Z)  
(2014-09-24 03:05:06,2014-09-24T03:05:06.000Z)  
(2014-09-24 03:27:30,2014-09-24T03:27:30.000Z)  
(2014-09-24 03:37:00,2014-09-24T03:37:00.000Z)  
(2014-09-24 03:39:18,2014-09-24T03:39:18.000Z)  
(2014-09-24 03:41:24,2014-09-24T03:41:24.000Z)  
(2014-09-24 03:43:18,2014-09-24T03:43:18.000Z)  
(2014-09-24 03:58:12,2014-09-24T03:58:12.000Z)
```

Please help.

Comment: similar error had occured to me had you found solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Pasting example from https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/datetime/convert/ISOToUnix.html:

```
REGISTER /Users/me/commiter/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar ; 
REGISTER /Users/me/commiter/piggybank/java/lib/joda-time-1.6.jar ; 
DEFINE ISOToUnix org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.convert.ISOToUnix(); 
ISOin = LOAD 'test.tsv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (dt:chararray, dt2:chararray); 

DESCRIBE ISOin; 
ISOin: {dt: chararray,dt2: chararray} 

DUMP ISOin; 
(2009-01-07T01:07:01.000Z,2008-02-01T00:00:00.000Z) 
(2008-02-06T02:06:02.000Z,2008-02-01T00:00:00.000Z) 
(2007-03-05T03:05:03.000Z,2008-02-01T00:00:00.000Z) 
... 

toUnix = FOREACH ISOin GENERATE ISOToUnix(dt) AS unixTime:long;

DESCRIBE toUnix; 
toUnix: {unixTime: long} 
DUMP toUnix; 
(1231290421000L)
(1202263562000L)
(1173063903000L) 
...
```

If you've noticed, dt (which is passed as param to ISOToUnix UDF is chararray. So you need to typecast your 'dt' column to chararray as below:

```
C = FOREACH B 
       GENERATE
           (chararray)(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING($0, 0,10),' '),
           SUBSTRING($0, 11,19) )) as   dt_string:chararray,
           CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING($0, 0,10),' '),SUBSTRING($0, 11,19) ) AS dt:chararray;

D = FOREACH C 
       GENERATE 
           dt_string, 
           dt, 
           ISOToUnix((chararray)dt)/1000 as epoch:long;

DUMP D;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help Guarav, I get the error **Cannot cast datetime to chararray**. I'll let this community know if I find another solution.